# How to delete an index from a firebase field array entirely

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

okay so what i am trying to achieve is delete the marked data when the elevated button is pressed here is the image [data inside firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRiUQ.png),

here is my code to upload data, its map right ?

```
            // setting received_request

            final data_2 = {
              "received_request" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([{ 
                "sender"   :  args.user_uid,
                "receiver" :  args.uid,
                "Name"     :  args.name_of,
                "status"   : "pending",
                "details"  :  {
                "date"              :  detail_class.datetime, 
                "total_dishes"      :  detail_class.total_dishes,                     
                "total_people"      :  detail_class.total_people,
                "meals"             :  detail_class.meals, 
                "location"          :  detail_class.location,
                "info"              :  detail_class.info,
                 }  
              }]), 
            };
             
             // sending received_request to the database

            db.collection("users").doc(args.uid).set(data_2, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

now what i want to achieve is delete the first index 0 when the user presses a button,
i have searched a lot and got to know that its possible through this FieldValue.arrayRemove()
now i have given FieldValue.arrayRemove() everyfield present inside the data but in vain,
i am lost at this point sorry my data structures are not great .

```
// delete it 
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
collection 
.doc(loggedInUser.uid)
.update( {
'received_request': FieldValue.arrayRemove([{ 
"sender"  : '${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index] ['sender']}',                                                    "receiver":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index ['receiver']}', 
"Name"    : '${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['Name']}',
"status"  : '${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['status']}',
"details" :  {
"date":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['date']}', 
"total_dishes":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['total_dishes']}',                     
"total_people":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['total_people']}',
"meals":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['meals']}', 
"location":'${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['location']}',
"info":  '${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]['details']['info']}',
   }  
 }]),
 }
);
```

Comment: How did you exactly use `arrayRemove`?

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> got to know that it's possible through this FieldValue.arrayRemove() now I have given FieldValue.arrayRemove() every field present inside the data but in vain.

Yes, that is correct. You can use `FieldValue.arrayRemove()` to remove a specific object from within an array. Your object wasn't removed because most likely you didn't pass an object which is the same as the one in the array. To have a match, the object that you pass, it's mandatory to have the exact fields and the exact values as the object in the database. It will not work with partial data or different data.

On the other hand, there is no way you can delete an element at a specific index in an array unless you read the document, delete the object from the array, and then write the document back to Firestore.

Comment: Hey Waseem. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: unfortunately below answer didn't worked, while i understand what are you saying i read the article too which is above me, i understand what i want to do, i want to remove the  ( map / object ) at index 0 from the received_request array, i have provided the same map to  FieldValue.arrayRemove() but still its not working , i am still debugging to see if i did something wrong somewhere thanks for your precious time

Comment: "didn't work"  doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly doesn't work? First of all, make sure it is the **exact** same object. First, use only two fields and you'll see that it will work. Give it a try and please conform to me that it worked.

Comment: i was not using the exact same object, some info was entered incorrect .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `set` with `SetOptions(merge: true)` when you delete, otherwise all other fields will be removed.

I also think that you don't have to repeat the entire map.

So try this:

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

collection 
  .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
  .set({
    'received_request': FieldValue.arrayRemove(
       [${snapshot.data[0]['received_request'][index]]),
   }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```